# What's the name of the non-radar-chart chart that looks like a triangle but has zero on the opposite edge?

Tags: terminology, graphing-functions

A radar chart has the value 0 at the center and then extends to 1 towards the vertices of the polygon, but I'm looking for one where the value goes from 0 from the opposite edge of the vertex.

[image]

Bonus question: Is this type of chart limited to triangles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are called [ternary plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_plot), plotting three variables that sum to a constant, and rely on [Viviani's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viviani%27s_theorem) for their correctness. Here's an example.

[image]

Two dimensions only suffice for plotting a system of variables with two degrees of freedom, although [an extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viviani%27s_theorem#Extensions) of Viviani's theorem means that a tetrahedron can be used to plot four variables that sum to a constant, and similarly for higher dimensions.